# Excel formula includes cell name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert an excel formula that I found to a more easily understood formula.  Below is the formula I'm trying to interpret.  What is ei??

=3*ei/2-27*ei^3/32

Comment: In the 'Name Box', in the upper left part of your Excel screen, type ei and hit enter.  This will take you right to cell ei.   The 'Name Box' is that little address box that shows you what cell address you are currently in.

Comment: thanks Space Odyssey, can you place an answer so that I can check your response as the answer for me?  'm new here and thats the only way I know how to give you credit

Comment: And here I thought we had imaginary Eulers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 'Name Box', in the upper left part of your Excel screen, type ei and hit enter. This will take you right to cell ei. The 'Name Box' is that little address box that shows you what cell address you are currently in.

If ei is actually the name of a cell, it will take you right to that cell.  If ei is not the name of a cell, typing ei in the 'Name Box' and hitting enter will give the name ei to the cell you are currently in.

You can also use the dropdown arrow for the 'Name Box' to see a list of all the named ranges and cells in the workbook.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to a cell named `ei`. When you paste this formula into Excel, it probably gives you the error `#NAME?` meaning there is no cell named `ei` You can either replace each ei in your formula to a cell reference or go to a cell and name it `ei` and put the value in there. Named cells are the same, but easier to read, form of absolute reference as `Sheet2!$C$4` for example.

Comment: I'm using excel 2003.  Any ideas how I can find which cell is ei?

Comment: I think in all versions of Excel I remember it is the pull down / scroll dohiche left of the formula bar that usually just has `b6` or whatever cell you are in. Highlight `b6` (or whatever current cell reference) to the current cell and type `ei` Know though that named cells are absolute so if you autofill your reference will not increment the same as a relative reference of the form `b6`

Comment: To find a named cell, use `Edit -> Go To...`